# Gmail PHP API gets wrong account emails

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-signin

I'm developing a PHP that reads the emails from gmail using the Gmail API.

Basically I'm doing exactly as the quickstart page does (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).

So firstly I load the client:

```
 require __DIR__ . '/Google/vendor/autoload.php';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
 $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
 $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
 $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
```

Then if I load the credentials from the db stored using an user id from my app.
If the credentials ar not present I do the redirect as the documentation sais:

```
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

After the authorization I get the access token using the code provided by google on my redirect url:

```
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
//storing the data in the db
header('Location: /index.php');
```

Of course if the token expires I do the refresh during the authentication process:

```
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken);
    $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $newToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshToken;
    //store the new token
}
```

So after this I can access the email list of my user, and it works perfectly.
The problem is that if I log in with my account, I see the correct email, but after loggin in with another account with another user I see the same emails form both accounts.

So for example if I authorize for the user 1 the account smith@gmail.com, then for the user 2 the email seth@gmail.com, in both cases I will see the same emails (from smith@gmail.com).

I have checked if the problem is mine, so if the access token loaded are the same, but is not like that unfortunately, the access tokens are different.

The other crazy thing is that if I refresh a token for the second account (smith@gmail.com), I will see the correct emails, but now seth, will see the smith emails.

What is going on? what I miss?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried every step and the problem is the access token, I've tried it also in another server but both returns the same emails.

I've also tried to get the auth code with seth@gmail.com and the manually I've retrieved the access token:

```
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
```

but no way, also doing this it will keeps authenticating me as the other email.

**UPDATE:**

The thing is getting stranger, I have tried to remove all part of the config file, and I use it only when I have to retrieve the auth code.

So in the request I pass only the access token array, what happens is that I can see the emails also completely removing the access token, so basically the client looks empty at the moment of the request.

```
(
[auth:Google_Client:private] => 
[http:Google_Client:private] => 
[cache:Google_Client:private] => 
[token:Google_Client:private] => Array
    (
        [access_token] => no token what so eva
    )

[config:Google_Client:private] => Array
    (
        [application_name] => 
        [base_path] => https://www.googleapis.com
        [client_id] => 
        [client_secret] => 
        [redirect_uri] => 
        [state] => 
        [developer_key] => 
        [use_application_default_credentials] => 
        [signing_key] => 
        [signing_algorithm] => 
        [subject] => 
        [hd] => 
        [prompt] => 
        [openid.realm] => 
        [include_granted_scopes] => 
        [login_hint] => 
        [request_visible_actions] => 
        [access_type] => online
        [approval_prompt] => auto
        [retry] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[logger:Google_Client:private] => 
[deferExecution:Google_Client:private] => 
[requestedScopes:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Comment: Have you tried the google oauth playground with the different access tokens, to see if it gets you the same result ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes, I've tried right now and they are workign correctly, witch both shows the correct email lists.

But, if In a PHP script they both returns the same emails list, so the problem is in the script, but is the same as the one in quickstart, can you give a look? (https://pastebin.com/SyqGrVQq)

Comment: Another detail I forgot, in the script I posted you, if I check the emails lists are the one from "smith@gmail.com" if I remove the access type, the scope and approval prompt line, it will show the "seth@gmail.com" emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by updating the client library to the latest version.